Swift using Family Controls to limit apps and get name of app
I am trying to use the familycontrols module to limit screen time of apps. The limiter works correctly but I want to be able to see the names of the apps that are limited in my Flutter app. I've tried everything and I can't figure out how to get the bundle ids of these apps.
I know that this is possible because there are app blockers that do this.
    for (index, token) in applications.applicationTokens.enumerated() {
        NSLog("Debug: test 1: \(applications)")
        NSLog("Debug: test 2: \(type(of: applications.applicationTokens.enumerated()))")
        NSLog("Debug: index: \(index)")
        NSLog("Debug: token: \(token)")
    }

This code gives the following output:
Debug: test 1: FamilyActivitySelection(includeEntireCategory: false, applicationTokens: Set([ApplicationToken(data: 128 bytes: `D^R'Ä¯ÅyñxnÆøH4sr;Øý³¶ï(DA^_ÒÖÜÄ~
Å^A¨u^O^ÎÕ^WÆG.aBÍEiÿ_n!jÜj¾U^Hi¼ý^[,H2v7cî·(o[Þò¤¤Þ^[ã/^Ní;ÿÙL^P=Ý ^]®+>¹·Á)]), categoryTokens: Set([]), webDomainTokens: Set([]), untokenizedApplicationIdentifiers: Set([]), untokenizedCategoryIdentifiers: Set([]), untokenizedWebDomainIdentifiers: Set([]))
Debug: test 2: EnumeratedSequence<Set<Token>>
Debug: index: 0
Debug: token: ApplicationToken(data: 128 bytes)
Here is some of my code (I added a lot because I have no idea what is happening):
DeviceActivityMonitorExtension.swift:
typealias ApplicationToken = ManagedSettings.Token<ManagedSettings.Application>
typealias ActivityCategoryToken = ManagedSettings.Token<ManagedSettings.ActivityCategory>

class DeviceActivityMonitorExtension: DeviceActivityMonitor {
    override func intervalDidStart(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalDidStart(for: activity)
    }
    
    override func intervalDidEnd(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalDidEnd(for: activity)
    }
    
        override func eventDidReachThreshold(_ event: DeviceActivityEvent.Name, activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.eventDidReachThreshold(event, activity: activity)
        
        NSLog("Threshold reached for event: \(event.rawValue)")
        
        // Retrieve stored tokens from shared UserDefaults
        guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID) else {
            NSLog("No app group defaults available.")
            return
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var applicationTokens: [ApplicationToken] = []
        var categoryTokens: [ActivityCategoryToken] = []
        
        // Decode application tokens from the new key
        if let appTokensData = defaults.data(forKey: Constants.limitedApplicationTokensKey) {
            if let tokens = try? decoder.decode([ApplicationToken].self, from: appTokensData) {
                applicationTokens = tokens
                NSLog("Decoded \(tokens.count) application tokens.")
            } else {
                NSLog("Failed to decode application tokens.")
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("No application tokens found in UserDefaults.")
        }
        
        // Decode category tokens if available
        if let catTokensData = defaults.data(forKey: Constants.limitedCategoryIdentifiersKey) {
            if let cats = try? decoder.decode([ActivityCategoryToken].self, from: catTokensData) {
                categoryTokens = cats
                NSLog("Decoded \(cats.count) category tokens.")
            } else {
                NSLog("Failed to decode category tokens.")
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("No category tokens found in UserDefaults.")
        }

        // Apply restrictions now that the threshold is reached
        let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
        
        // If we have no application tokens, set nil; otherwise, set them as a Set
        store.shield.applications = applicationTokens.isEmpty ? nil : Set(applicationTokens)
        
        // For categories, we use a specific policy if we have any
        store.shield.applicationCategories = categoryTokens.isEmpty
            ? nil
            : ShieldSettings.ActivityCategoryPolicy.specific(Set(categoryTokens))
        
        NSLog("Restrictions applied. The selected apps and categories should now show the Restricted screen.")
    }

    override func intervalWillStartWarning(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalWillStartWarning(for: activity)
    }
    
    override func intervalWillEndWarning(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalWillEndWarning(for: activity)
    }
    
    override func eventWillReachThresholdWarning(_ event: DeviceActivityEvent.Name, activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.eventWillReachThresholdWarning(event, activity: activity)
    }
}


MyModel:
import Foundation
import FamilyControls
import ManagedSettings

private let _MyModel = MyModel()

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
    
    @Published var selectionToDiscourage: FamilyActivitySelection
    @Published var selectionToEncourage: FamilyActivitySelection
    @Published var selectionToLimit: FamilyActivitySelection
    
    init() {
        selectionToDiscourage = FamilyActivitySelection()
        selectionToEncourage = FamilyActivitySelection()
        selectionToLimit = FamilyActivitySelection()
    }
    
    class var shared: MyModel {
        return _MyModel
    }
    func setShieldRestrictions() {
        NSLog("Debug: Setting shield restrictions for discouraged apps: \(selectionToDiscourage.applicationTokens)")
        let applications = self.selectionToDiscourage
        store.shield.applications = applications.applicationTokens.isEmpty ? nil : applications.applicationTokens
        store.shield.applicationCategories = applications.categoryTokens.isEmpty
            ? nil
            : ShieldSettings.ActivityCategoryPolicy.specific(applications.categoryTokens)
    }

    // Used to encode codable to UserDefaults
    private let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()

    // Used to decode codable from UserDefaults
    private let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    
    func saveFamilyActivitySelection(selection: FamilyActivitySelection) {
        NSLog("Debug: selected app updated: ", selection.applicationTokens.count," category: ", selection.categoryTokens.count)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        defaults.set(
            try? encoder.encode(selection),
            forKey: "limitedApplicationTokens"
        )
        
        //check is data saved to user defaults
        getSavedFamilyActivitySelection()
    }
    
    //get saved family activity selection from UserDefault
    func getSavedFamilyActivitySelection() -> FamilyActivitySelection? {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let data = defaults.data(forKey: "limitedApplicationTokens") else {
            return nil
        }
        var selectedApp: FamilyActivitySelection?
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        selectedApp = try? decoder.decode(FamilyActivitySelection.self, from: data)
        
        NSLog("Debug: saved selected app updated: ", selectedApp?.categoryTokens.count ?? "0")
        return selectedApp
    }

}

AppDelegate.swift:
func clearLimitedAppsData() {
    guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: Constants.appGroupID) else { return }
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: Constants.limitedApplicationBundleIdentifiersKey)
    defaults.synchronize()
    NSLog("Debug: Cleared limitedApplicationBundleIdentifiersKey data.")
}

var globalMethodCall = ""

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {

        // clearLimitedAppsData()

        guard let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
            return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        }
        
        let METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME = "flutter_screentime"
        
        let model = MyModel.shared
        let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
        
        let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) in
            Task {
                // Request authorization for Family Controls if available
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    do {
                        try await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
                        NSLog("Debug: Authorization request succeeded.")
                    } catch {
                        NSLog("Debug: Authorization request failed with error: \(error)")
                        result(FlutterError(code: "AUTH_ERROR", message: "Authorization failed", details: nil))
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog("Debug: iOS version is below 16.0, cannot proceed.")
                    result(FlutterError(code: "iOS_VERSION_ERROR", message: "iOS 16.0 or newer is required", details: nil))
                    return
                }
                
                switch call.method {
                case "blockApp":
                    globalMethodCall = "selectAppsToDiscourage"
                    NSLog("Debug: Presenting blockApp picker.")
                    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
                        .environmentObject(model)
                        .environmentObject(store))
                    controller.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    result("blockApp invoked")
                    
                case "unblockApp":
                    globalMethodCall = "selectAppsToEncourage"
                    NSLog("Debug: Presenting unblockApp picker.")
                    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
                        .environmentObject(model)
                        .environmentObject(store))
                    controller.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    result("unblockApp invoked")
                    
                case "limitApp":
                    globalMethodCall = "selectAppsToLimit"
                    NSLog("Debug: Presenting limitApp picker.")
                    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
                        .environmentObject(model)
                        .environmentObject(store))
                    controller.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    result("limitApp invoked")
                    
                case "getLimitedApps":
                    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                        let limitedApps = self.decodeLimitedApps()
                        NSLog("Debug: Returning limited apps: \(limitedApps)")
                        result(limitedApps)
                    } else {
                        NSLog("Debug: iOS < 16.0, cannot get limited apps.")
                        result(["No limited apps or iOS < 16.0"])
                    }
                    
                default:
                    NSLog("Debug: Unhandled method call: \(call.method)")
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
            }
        }
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    @available(iOS 16.0, *)
func decodeLimitedApps() -> [String] {
    guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: Constants.appGroupID) else {
        NSLog("Debug: No app group defaults available.")
        return ["No limited apps found."]
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    var limitedApps: [String] = []
    
    NSLog("Debug: Attempting to read limited apps from UserDefaults.")
    if let appBundleIDsData = defaults.data(forKey: Constants.limitedApplicationBundleIdentifiersKey) {
        NSLog("Debug: Found app bundle IDs data: \(appBundleIDsData.count) bytes")
        
        // Decode the data as [String]
        do {
            let bundleIDs = try decoder.decode([String].self, from: appBundleIDsData)
            if !bundleIDs.isEmpty {
                NSLog("Debug: Decoded bundle IDs: \(bundleIDs)")
                limitedApps = bundleIDs
                for bundleID in bundleIDs {
                    NSLog("Bundle Identifier: \(bundleID)")
                }
            } else {
                NSLog("Debug: Decoded bundle IDs array is empty.")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("Debug: Failed to decode bundle IDs: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // Optionally, log the raw data as a string for inspection
            if let rawString = String(data: appBundleIDsData, encoding: .utf8) {
                NSLog("Debug: Raw appBundleIDsData as String: \(rawString)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("Debug: No app bundle IDs data found in UserDefaults.")
    }
    
    if limitedApps.isEmpty {
        return ["No limited apps found!"]
    }
    
    return limitedApps
}




func storeLimitedApps(bundleIDs: [String], categoryIDs: [String]) {
    guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: Constants.appGroupID) else {
        NSLog("Debug: Failed to access UserDefaults with App Group ID.")
        return
    }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    do {
        let appData = try encoder.encode(bundleIDs)
        defaults.set(appData, forKey: Constants.limitedApplicationBundleIdentifiersKey)
        NSLog("Debug: Stored \(bundleIDs.count) application bundle identifiers: \(bundleIDs)")
    } catch {
        NSLog("Debug: Failed to encode application bundle identifiers: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Similarly handle categoryIDs if necessary
    do {
        let catData = try encoder.encode(categoryIDs)
        defaults.set(catData, forKey: Constants.limitedCategoryIdentifiersKey)
        NSLog("Debug: Stored \(categoryIDs.count) category identifiers.")
    } catch {
        NSLog("Debug: Failed to encode category identifiers: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    defaults.synchronize()
}



}




Your main app cannot get the names of the apps nor their identifiers.  This is a deliberate, privacy-preserving feature of the Device Activity Framework.
The framework provides UI classes that are used to manage app selection.  All your app can access is the opaque tokens that represent the apps that is provided by these UI classes.  You cannot build your own UI for these operations.
If you want to provide a custom report screen then you need to implement a Device Activity Report Extension.  This extension can provide one or more DeviceActivityReport views.
This extension runs in its own sandbox and is not capable of communicating over the network or moving sensitive data out of its own address space. It can, however, read data that has been shared by your main app.
Your extension will receive DeviceActivityData elements that describe applications, websites and the activity time via the makeConfiguration method of your extension's DeviceActivityReportScene.
You will need to implement this extension in Swift and SwiftUI.  You can't implement it in Flutter/Dart.
The best way to get started is to open your project in Xcode and add a "Device Activity Report extension" target; This will include some sample code that shows how to create the extension.

how do other apps do this then? For example the app Opal allows me to block any app and when I select Instagram it later shows Instagram on the Opal's UI - not something built in like the app selector tool.

I have updated my answer to include details of the device activity report API

Thank you for your help so far. I tried using your advice with DeviceActivityReport but I seem to be stuck with the same results as before I used it. Could you please provide me with a code snippet specifically to get the names of these limited apps? (And also which of the three sample Swift files I should be adding it to)

You should be able to use something like this in makeConfiguration - I don't have a functioning device activity app, so I can't test it
